# Terraform block of type serverlessv2_scaling_configuration are not expected here

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-aurora-serverless

I am trying to provision an AWS Aurora Postgres Serverless v2 using Terraform. I read the documentation [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/rds_cluster) and it said, it only needs these parameters:

- `engine_mode` set to `"provisioned"`
- `serverlessv2_scaling_configuration` in the cluster
- `resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance"` with `instance_class` set to `"db.serverless"`

But I got this error returned

```
╷
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│ 
│   on ../../modules/postgres_serverless_v2/main.tf line 70, in resource "aws_rds_cluster" "pg":
│   70:   serverlessv2_scaling_configuration {
│ 
│ Blocks of type "serverlessv2_scaling_configuration" are not expected here.
```

I'm not really sure what to do next as I try to search for solution but everyone seems to be having no issue with this.

Below is the snippet of my code:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "pg" {
  cluster_identifier      = "${var.namespace}-${var.env_name}-${var.name}-pg-v2"
  engine                  = "aurora-postgresql"
  engine_version          = null
  engine_mode             = "provisioned"  # still using serverless. requirement from terraform
  port                    = var.pg_port
  db_subnet_group_name    = aws_db_subnet_group.subnet_grp_pg.name
  vpc_security_group_ids  = [aws_security_group.sec_grp_pg.id]
  availability_zones      = data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names
  database_name           = "${var.namespace}_${var.env_name}_${var.name}"
  master_username         = var.pg_username
  master_password         = random_password.this.result
  kms_key_id              = var.kms_key_arn
  backup_retention_period = var.backup_retention_period
  # preferred_backup_window   = "02:30-04:30"  # Arg. causes an issue when building from snapshot, leave commented out to mitigate. 
  final_snapshot_identifier = "${var.namespace}-${var.name}-${var.env_name}-pg-rds-backup-${formatdate("YYYYMMDD-hhmmss", timestamp())}"
  snapshot_identifier       = var.snapshot_identifier
  skip_final_snapshot       = false
  storage_encrypted         = true
  enable_http_endpoint      = true
  apply_immediately         = true

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      availability_zones
    ]
  }

  serverlessv2_scaling_configuration {
    min_capacity = 0.5
    max_capacity = 128.0
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.namespace}-${var.env_name}-${var.name}-pg-v2"
    Environment = "${var.env_name}"
    Origin      = "terraform"
    App         = var.name
  }
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "pg" {
  cluster_identifier = aws_rds_cluster.pg.id
  instance_class = "db.serverless"
  engine = aws_rds_cluster.pg.engine
  engine_version = aws_rds_cluster.pg.engine_version
}
```

P.S. I'm using Terraform v1.2.4

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind. It's my mistake that I'm still using aws providers on version `3.72`, while the serverlessv2 is just supported after `v4.15.0` showed in this [release version link](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/v4.15.0/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Guess who else made the same mistake. This guy. Thanks.